# How to change the Views exposed filter format from a select box to a slider element?

Tags: 8, views

I want to change the ways Views presents the exposed filter. Currently it shows as a select box and I'd like it as a slider for a timeline effect. I've looked at the following modules, but they have either not been ported to D8 yet, or don't offer (from playing around with them) what I'm after:

- Slide With Style
- Contextual Range Filter
- Better Exposed Filters

Any suggestions on how I can make this work?

Comment: i think you can use better expose filter, and convert select options as link ul li format and use them according to your need